# Jest not transforming CSS file import statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jestjs, webpacker

#### Some context:

I'm working on a Rails app and I've set up React-rails and Jest via the Webpacker gem.  I'm new to most of this stack, so please bear with me.  My problem arises in Jest when I import some CSS in a component like so

```
//some_component.jsx
import('react-datetime/css/react-datetime.css')
//or even any local CSS
import('./any_local_css.css')

yarn test

import('react-datetime/css/react-datetime.css');
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

#### What I've tried:

I went through [the Jest docs for working with webpack](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html) and *several* Github issues for the listed technologies like [this one](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3094) which suggests using the `moduleNameMapper` option in the Jest config in my `package.json` like the Jest docs do, the `transform` option.

The main issue I'm running into is that the only module map that will work is one like this:

`"moduleNameMapper": { ".*": "<rootDir>/path/to/mock.js" }`

#### The problem with that:

since it's `.*`, I think it's going ahead and transforming *all* my modules, including the one with the test itself.  So when I run the test with `yarn test`, I start to get errors about the enzyme adapter's constructor: 
`TypeError: _enzymeAdapterReact2.default is not a constructor`.  This is not an error I get when I remove the mapping and the css import.

The example in the Jest docs want me to use `\\.(css)$` instead of `.*` but that won't match anything, and I'm back with the first error.

A few questions about this:

- Why is the regex syntax so different for `moduleNameMapper` and `transform`?  Those matchers for a CSS file seem pretty much the same
- do either of those matchers find CSS files in your `node_modules` directory?

### My setup

Here is how I have my JS files saved as suggested by Webpacker/React-rails:

```
app
├── javascript
|   ├── components
|   |   └── my_component.jsx
|   └── src
|       └── my_css.css
├── test
|   └── suites
|       └── javascript
|           ├── src 
|           |   └── testSetup.jsx
|           └── my_test.jsx
├── node_modules
└── package.json
```

#### package.json

```
  "jest": { 
    "moduleNameMapper": { 
      "\\.(css)$": ""
    },
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/test/suites/javascript/src/testSetup.jsx",
    "moduleDirectories": [ 
      "node_modules",
      "app/javascript/components",
      "app/javascript/src"
    ],
    "roots": [ 
      "test/suites/javascript"
    ] 
  }
```

#### testSetup.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { mount, shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

#### my_test.jsx

```
import MyComponent from 'MyComponent'

describe('<MyComponent> />', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    const wrapper == shallow((<MyComponent/>));
    expect(wrapper.find('#some_id').toHaveLength(1);
  }
}
```

#### More stuff I've tried

- Using the `import css from 'react-datetime/css/react-datetime.css'` syntax inside my component, but then the CSS doesn't actually show up on the page, it gets nixed by something called `extract-text-plugin`, but doesn't seem to place it anywhere that gets interpreted.
- Using jest-css-modules, but the Github page for that mentions that I "likely" won't need it, specifically because of what Jest is doing now with modulemapping/transforming
- Follow the [webpack 2 portion of the Jest docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html#using-with-webpack-2) and add babel (I am doing it directly in my `package.json` file instead of my `.babelrc` since I don't believe I have one
- Using the `transform` option with `identity-obj-proxy` (tried once with the contents of the mock file containing what it says to on the jest docs, and one on the identity-obj-proxy github readme`

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Create a Rails 4.2 app
2. Install the Webpacker gem and `bundle exec rake webpacker:install`
3. Install ReactRails `bundle exec rake webpacker:install:react`
4. Make a component `bundle exec rails g react:component HelloWorld`
5. Install React-datetime `yarn add react-datetime` OR create some css in `app/javascript/src/css.css`
6. Import the css in

#### Current Workaround

The workaround is pretty simple - import your CSS however you want in your `app/javascript/packs/application.js` and Jest doesn't have to know anything about it.  It just might be awkward when you end up with several CSS imports in your `application.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

This jest config worked for me :

```
{
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".*css$": "<rootDir>/src/stub.css",
    }
}
```

(Remember to create `stub.css`)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  If I use `import('datetime.css')` from my `node_modules`, the CSS shows up fine on the page but still fails the tests as opposed to `import css from('datetime.css')`, which doesn't render the CSS properly, but passes the test.  So somehow, Jest is not actually mocking the CSS.  The docs also say to use a .JS file for the mock, not a CSS.

Comment: you should just write `import 'datetime.css';` `import()` is a webpack and future thing of node where, which imports as a promise, that is why it doesnt really work. Try `import 'datetime.css';` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In my package.json, I do:

```
"jest": {
"verbose": true,
"testURL": "https://test.domain.com",
"testPathIgnorePatterns": ["config/*"],
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/app/javascript/lib/CSSStub.js"
  }
},
```

Where app/javascript/lib/CSSStub.js is just

```
module.exports = {};
```

Comment: Could you also add your `.babelrc` contents?  I think my issue might be somewhere in there.

Comment: I'd double check that you have babel-jest added as a devDependency

Here is the babelrc you requested
https://gist.github.com/danielpowell4/39b94a16d763090ad69d57f32b8a9070#babelrc

Be sure that the plugins are also listed as dependencies in package.json

Hope this helps